# Titanium ios, PayPal Direct Payment API

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

Was anybody able to use PayPal Direct Payment API with Titanium. I want to be able to process payments in background without firing up a webview or authentication view. If there is any example so please let me know. Thank you

Comment: yes I explored paypal API for titanium and its documentation but I didn't find anything like this.

Comment: I worked on paypal API with webview or authentication view. it works fine. But didn't find anything direct payment through paypal :(

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no SDK of Paypal for Titanium (not sure) and You need to make a module of iOS paypal sdk..